# How do you customize the Route on abp CrudAppService / AsyncCrudAppService

Tags: c#, asp.net, abp

I am experimenting with the abp CrudAppService (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Application-Services#crud-application-services), which allows me to set up CRUD endpoints with minimal code.

As an example, I can create the following base class:

```
public class BaseAsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TDto> : AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,
    TDto, TDto> where TEntity : class, IEntity<Guid> where TDto : IEntityDto<Guid>
{
    public BaseAsyncCrudAppService(IRepository<TEntity, Guid> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {

    }
}
```

And then create enpoint sets like these:

```
public class MyFooAppService : BaseAsyncCrudAppService<MyFooEntity, MyFooDto>,
    IMyFooAppService
{
    
    public MyFooAppService(IRepository<MyFooEntity, Guid> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
}
```

And

```
public class MyBarAppService : BaseAsyncCrudAppService<MyBarEntity, MyBarDto>,
    IMyBarAppService
{
    
    public MyBarAppService(IRepository<MyBarEntity, Guid> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
}
```

This will produce the following endpoints:

```
GET /api/services/app/MyFoo/Get
GET /api/services/app/MyFoo/GetAll
POST /api/services/app/MyFoo/Create
PUT /api/services/app/MyFoo/Update
DELETE /api/services/app/MyFoo/Delete


GET /api/services/app/MyBar/Get
GET /api/services/app/MyBar/GetAll
POST /api/services/app/MyBar/Create
PUT /api/services/app/MyBar/Update
DELETE /api/services/app/MyBar/Delete
```

What I would like to know is how I could alter the path where these endpoints get served. I don't need to do it individually for each method, but I would like to set it for example

```
GET /api/services/app/baz/MyFoo/Get
GET /api/services/app/baz/MyFoo/GetAll
POST /api/services/app/baz/MyFoo/Create
PUT /api/services/app/baz/MyFoo/Update
DELETE /api/services/baz/app/MyFoo/Delete
```

If were to code the endpoints manually, I would do it like this:

```
[Route("api/services/app/baz/[controller]/Get")]
public async Task GetMyFoo(Guid id)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this on class level on the `MyFooAppService` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate the base class with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route attribute, e.g. `[Route("/api/services/app/baz/[controller]")]`.

```
[Route("/api/services/app/baz/[controller]")]
public class BaseAsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TDto> : AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,
    TDto, TDto> where TEntity : class, IEntity<Guid> where TDto : IEntityDto<Guid>
{
    public BaseAsyncCrudAppService(IRepository<TEntity, Guid> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {

    }
}
```

To customize the routes of the individual endpoints, you can override the methods and decorate them with [HTTP verb attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#http-verbs),

For example, `[HttpGet("/new/root/here")]`

```
[HttpGet("/new/root/here")]
public override Task<TDto> GetAsync(EntityDto<Guid> id)
{
   return base.GetAsync(id);
}
```

would produce endpoint

```
GET  /new/root/here/
```

To extend the route specified on class level, omit the leading '/'.

For example
`[HttpGet("sub/root/here/")]` would make the endpoint available at

```
GET  /api/services/app/baz/[controller]/sub/root/here/
```